# SQL Server 2008 R2 memory limit per instance or server?

Tags: licensing, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm getting ready to deploy a new SQL server and realized that the memory limit of SQL Server 2008 R2 is supposedly 64GB of RAM (http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/product-info/compare.aspx). Potentially an upside, there will be many instances of SQL server on this box. Does anybody know if the 64GB limitation is per server or per instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm reasonably confident that it's per-instance. If you want a simple way to test just to see for sure, fire up a few instances of Express, which is limited to 1 GB.

Comment: I'll have to give that a shot. Doesn't look like I'll get a concrete answer unless I do so. :-)

Comment: I fired up two instances of SQL Express 2008 R2 on a Win7 x64 machine with 6GB of RAM and attached two moderately sized databases to each instance. I ran a query and, according to Task Manager, had one instance running with 800MB of RAM utilized and another running with 760MB utilized. It looks like it's a per-instance limit :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe those named-instances installed under Standard Edition will all utilize the same 64 gb of memory on your server.