# SQL2008R2Std Maximum RAM per instance

Tags: sql-server, licensing

In this page : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143685%28v=sql.105%29.aspx
It's written that SQL 2008R2 Standard supports 64GB of RAM, but is it *per instance*?

For SQL2012 (here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/cc645993.aspx )  it's written that it's "For a single instance", but not for 2008R2.

This question has already been asked ([SQL Server 2008 R2 memory limit per instance or server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/230862/sql-server-2008-r2-memory-limit-per-instance-or-server)) but the answer comes from a test (and not with 64GB), so i'm not sure it will work for me :-)

The goal for me is to get a server with 128GB RAM, with two SQLSERVER2008R2STD, each with 64BG RAM (minus the OS-requiered).

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's per instance.

From the [**Server Memory Options page on TechNet**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178067%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

> Use max server memory to control memory usage. Establish maximum
>   settings for each instance, being careful that the total allowance is
>   not more than the total physical memory on your machine.

1st bullet under the Running Multiple Instances of SQL Server section toward the bottom.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes I'll be careful and will keep a safety amount of RAM.

Answer (score 0):

As every instance of SQL Server is a separate process, it's more logical that the limit is per instance.

Coordinating memory usage between different processes is something very complex. What if one process gets greedy and consumes the memory 'pooled' between several processes? What if the other processes don't want to give up memory? You'll easily end up with a race condition, bringing everything to a halt.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The SQL Server's memory will be strictly regulated by max and min's server memory settings.